# Copying text from a .txt file and assigning it into a variable in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to take some text from a file and copy the text and assign it to a variable. How should I do that?

Text file (text.txt):

```
test
```

The text file is in the same folder as the Python file below:
Part of a Python file (test.py):

```
info = "test"
```

So, how do I copy the text from the text.txt file and assign it to the **info** variable in test.py?

Comment: If you do the official Python tutorial, there is a section which explains how to read and write text files.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask]. It seems like you haven't even tried looking for a solution yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple:

```
with open('text.txt', 'r') as file:
    info = file.read().rstrip('\n')
```

Comment: Add `.rstrip('\n')` to remove trailing newline(s)